# Getting value from angularjs scope object

Tags: php, angularjs

I have the following angularjs code for posting value to php:

```
$scope.aToUn = function(aName) {
    //$scope.question.question_16 =UnionsId;
    var outputType=[{type:'aName',action:'none',PassId:aName}];

    $http.post('addressManagement.php',outputType).success(function(dataJsonUnions) {
        //alert(dataJsonUnions);
        $scope.question =dataJsonUnions;

        //question or dataJsonUnions is an object that passed from json, 
        //something like question={{id="2",questionvalue="Name"}}
        //calling another function 
        $scope.anotherFunction(questionvalue); // here i want to pass only value that from json eg. 'Name' only)
    });
};
```

I am getting json object value, which i want to do something with that only single value. (object contain only one single value, dont want if/else or foreach)

Comment: You can simply use `var questionvalue = $scope.question.questionvalue` and then pass `questionvalue` into the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try

`$scope.anotherFunction($scope.question[0].questionvalue);`

Answer (score 0):

As i understand your question, You first need to conver json response to object by using angular.fromJson() and then pass object's property for example:

```
$scope.question = angular.fromJson(dataJsonUnions);
```

then call function with argument that you want to pass:

```
 $scope.anotherFunction($scope.question.questionvalue);
```

hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

If the response is a JSON object and if you want to access the value of field 'questionValue' then you can try the below.

```
var json = JSON.parse(dataJsonUnions);
json.questionValue; // THis will fetch you the value
//OR
json['questionValue'];
// Then you can pass this value to any function that you need
```